# Apache Camel: How to modify XSLT before it is applied to XML

Tags: spring, xslt, groovy, apache-camel

**The Problem:**
I have some XSLT files on the classpath. These are sometimes reformatted unintentionally by some colleagues' IDE such that line breaks are introduced. This introduces line breaks in the transformed XMLs causing a series of other issues.

**My question is:** 
How can I modify the XSLT before it is applied to the XML files within a camel route.

Please do not give alternative suggestion on how to solve the problem. I would like to learn more about camel and its internals.

My route would look something like that:

```
@Component
class SomeRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired  
    SomeProcessor someProcessor

    XStream xStream = new XStream()

    @Override
    void configure() {
        xStream.alias("SomeTag", SomeClass.class)

        from("direct:some-endpoint")
            .streaming()
            .to("xslt://xslt/SomeXsltWithLineBreaks.xsl?saxon=true")
            .split(xpath("//SomeTag"))
            .unmarshal(new XStreamDataFormat(xStream))
            .process(someProcessor)
            .end()
    }
}
```

I've tried the following but it is never triggered:

```
intercept().when(body().contains("stylesheet"))
        .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "iso-8859-1")
        .setBody(body().regexReplaceAll("\\r\\n", "\\\n"))
```

Comment: You would need to read the xslt file from a file endpoint, do the search and replace and write the xslt to file again. Then use that file in your route. Best would be to create a seperate route to do the search and replace.

Comment: Hi :) No, this doesn't seem to work, since the file is on the classpath within a jar and it seems not possible to write the file. Otherwise I've tried the following already: https://pastebin.com/baSBs8EH

Comment: Ohh.. maybe you ment I need to write the file to anywhere else on the FS first..

Comment: Yes, I meant write somewhere else on the FS. Then consume from there and use that to do your XSLT.